# how can we add the functionality in button of divi theme of wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am using divi theme in wordpress for my site. and i add one header using page builder. I want that only logged in user can clicked on shop now button and if they are not logged in then they will redirect to login page

Answer (score 0):

You are asking about quite basic functionality of the WordPress API:

*boolean* [is_user_logged_in()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_user_logged_in)

If you are modifying the theme directly or have enabled a plugin that lets you use PHP-code on your pages and posts, you can use this Wordpress-/PHP-function in combination with a PHP [if-statement](http://php.net/manual/control-structures.if.php) to check whether the current user is logged in and, in case he or she is, add really anythingto your page. Ok, except for a living unicorn.

```
<?php if ( is_user_logged_in() ) : ?>

<a href="linktoyourshoppingpage">Shop Now</a>

<?php endif; ?>
```

You said if the current user of your web-page is not logged in, he or she is supposed to be redirected to the login-page. The [else-statement](http://php.net/manual/control-structures.else.php) is probably what you are looking for. And, if you are brave enough, try not to hard-code the login link here by making use of the WordPress API-function [wp_login_url()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_login_url):

```
<?php if ( is_user_logged_in() ) : ?>

<a href="linktoyourshoppingpage">Shop Now</a>

<?php else:  ?>

<a href="<?php echo wp_login_url(); ?>">Log In to shop</a>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Remember, if you want to use this code on your wordpress pages, articles, widgets, whatever..., you have to install a plugin that lets you use PHP there. Also, this code is not completly free of [avoidable repetitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) for the sake of making the examples easy to understand. It should be easy to figure out how to optimize the code.

Comment: hi,..but i only use html, java and jquery. and  i got current user name by using shortcode [currentuser_username]\

Comment: @prakash-jha: If you want to use JavaScript for this (which I would highly recommend not to do) this might be of help to you:

[Wordpress - Check if user is logged in using JQuery](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/69814/check-if-user-is-logged-in-using-jquery)